# Visual Studio- way to see the stack size growing whilst stepping through?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I know the call stack window shows all the function calls, but is there a way to see the size of the stack grow/shrink whilst stepping through the code?

I am using VS2012

Google just keeps returning how to increase the stack size...

Answer (score 2):

The stack size is fixed, the default is one megabyte.  You can certainly see your code *consuming* space in the stack, the value of the ESP register, the stack pointer, is visible in the Debug + Windows + Registers window.  Note that it will *decrease* as you step into functions.

Comment: Is this different on different architectures? I don’t see that register.

Answer (score 1):

The stack actually doesn't change size while running.  Each thread has a specific [Thread Stack Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is compiled into the executable.

There is no direct way to see the amount of the stack which is currently in use within the Visual Studio debugging environment, either, if that's what you would like to see.

Comment: Yes thats what I was after. I am sure I have allocated most of my objects on the heap but I am still getting a stack overflow- so I am unsure how to see what exactly is causing it...

Comment: @user If you're running out of stack space Windows will generate an exception. You can set up Visual Studio to break into the debugger when this happens. Go to *Debug* -> *Exceptions...*. Under *Win32 Exceptions* click the *Thrown* checkbox for *0xc00000fd Stack overflow*.

Comment: @user Clicking *Break* takes you right into the debugger, to the faulting location. You get to see the entire call stack, which is usually very helpful to diagnose the issue, like a deep recursion.